# GDB: How to add a key combination which runs a command?

Tags: configuration, gdb, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using `GNU gdb (GDB) 7.10.1` with the `-tui` mode. I would like to add a key combination for the commands `up` and `down`. Something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> for `up` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> for `down`.

I've seen only comments about readline but not an example explaining how to integrate the combination in the gdb init file. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a TUI user, but my understanding is that the TUI has two modes.

In its initial (normal) mode, it uses readline like the ordinary gdb CLI.  Readline provides [a way to rebind keys](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Readline-Init-File.html#Readline-Init-File) via `~/.inputrc`.  The main thing you need to know here is that gdb is, sensibly enough, called "gdb" for readline's purposes.  So a binding might look like:

```
$if gdb
"\C-u": "up\n"
$endif
```

The TUI also has a "single key" mode.  As far as I know, this mode doesn't use readline and there is no way to rebind keys.  However, in this mode, "u" and "d" are already bound the way you'd like.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. You made my day. `\n` didn't work correctly, `\C-m` is the equivalent to `Enter`.

Comment: This is great, but I'm having trouble getting function keys to work. They are fine before I switch to TUI, but then start acting weird afterwards