# How to clear gdb screen completely?

Tags: gdb

I'm using this in `~/.bashrc` to clear the terminal with F12:

```
bind '"\e[24~": "\C-k\C-u echo -ne \047\\0033\\0143\047\n"'
```

Obviously, that doesn't affect gdb or any other program that is launched by the terminal.

It seems that this clears correctly if typed into gdb prompt:

```
!echo -ne "\033\0143"
```

So, how to properly clear the gdb screen, so you can't scroll back at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And using https://stackoverflow.com/a/35801000/4742108 , the final solution is to add to `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\e[24~":'!echo -ne \047\\0033\\0143\047\r'
```

That works because gdb uses the readline library.

Comment: To do that binding for gdb only, you'd better enclose it with '$if (gdb) ...$endif'.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34960428/1820106

Answer (score 0):

That's up to the terminal emulator, the scrollback is a terminal emulator feature.

[This answer over on apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/113168) says that some terminal emulators implement an extension to the ANSI standard that allows this:

```
printf '\e[3J'
```

Where `printf` is the bash command. So, the equivalent echo in gdb should work, if your terminal emulator implements this.