# Can we set keybindings in GDB?

Tags: gdb

Is it possible to bind a command to a single button in GDB, F12 for example?

(as usual, don't try to sell emacs or find out "what are you trying to do")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gdb uses the [readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html) library, so you could put the following in `~/.inputrc` to bind <kbd>F12</kbd> to the `continue` command:

```
"\e[24~":"continue\r"
```